# firebase_messaging dependecy consistency with the project

Tags: firebase, flutter, dependencies, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have some questions and I would love to get answers because it's the first time that I develop using Flutter and Google services.

So I've been following a course on Udemy and it was created in 2020 but never updated and now after developping the half of the project I've faced a problem with Firebase Messaging, in the course the used version was 7.0.3 and now the latest version is 9.1.4 and a lot has changed.

I tried to install the 7.0.3 version but it didn't work !
Can you suggest any solution because as I said I'm a beginner and even by following some documentations, I find myself stuck and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, please post the code of you trying to install the 7.0.3 version and also post the error message.

Comment: Because firebase_messaging >=7.0.3 <8.0.0-dev.7 depends on firebase_core ^0.5.0+1 and driver_app depends on firebase_core ^1.1.0, firebase_messaging >=7.0.3 <8.0.0-dev.7 is forbidden.
And these are all the dependencies installed :
firebase_core: ^1.1.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.2
  firebase_database: ^6.1.2
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.6
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.3
  geolocator: ^7.0.3
  http: ^0.13.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.1
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
  flutter_geofire: ^2.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^9.1.4
Should I downgrade all?

Comment: You just need to use a compatible version. Checkout my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your dependencies are not compatible.
To solve this, you need to use compatible versions of `firebase_core` and `firebase_messaging`.

Your `firebase_core` version is `1.1.0` and the corresponding `firebase_messaging`version is `9.1.3` as shown below, so you should use `9.1.3` to remove the error.

```yaml
    // pubspec.yaml of the firebase_messaging plugin

    name: firebase_messaging
    // ...
    repository: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging
    version: 9.1.3
    
    // ...
    
    dependencies:
      firebase_core: ^1.1.0
   
    //...
```

[Source](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/79d6a62ebd429a728637909f6c4ea62e373ee9fd/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/pubspec.yaml)

Comment: What if I want to work with 7.0.3 should downgrade firebase_core to 0.5.0+1 ?